# Мониторинг транзакций от сессии ODAC

Tags: delphi, oracle, plsql, odac

Имеются компоненты `ODAC`, в процессе работы программы исполняется куча различных хранимых процедур и запросов, они хранятся как транзакция в ожидании `commit` или `rollback` внутри одной сессии. Существует ли способ мониторинга и логирования транзакции от сессии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Из документации ODAC](https://docs.devart.com/odac/using_dbmonitor.htm)

1. Добавляем на форму TOraSQLMonitor
2. Выбираем параметры для мониторинга (тэг `mo`, например `moDBMonitor`)
3. Выбираем в параметрах компонентов ODAC `Debug:=True`
4. Запускаем программу [DBMonitor](https://www.devart.com/dbmonitor/)
5. Производим запуск и отладку приложения